# Google Prebuilt VM

Tags: cloud

I need some help. I think it's a bug, but lets see..
I live in Japan so all prices are listed in JPY.

So I see this prebuilt VM from Google Cloud and it says it will only cost 111JPY per month? That's equivalent of $1! So I guess it's something wrong or the conversion from USD to JPY is wrong.
[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQLZb.jpg)

See image.

Anyone had similar issues? I tried to contact Google directly but looks like I dont have access to it.